# Scrapy authenticated crawl

Tags: python, security, web, scrapy, web-crawler

I tried using Scrapy to crawl the pages of [WackoPicko](https://github.com/adamdoupe/WackoPicko) and have been stuck at this page, http://localhost/pictures/view.php?picid=3, where there is supposedly a comment box below.

I have tried using just a single cookiejar to make sure my authenticated session is passed through to all the links once I've logged in, and have tweaked around with most settings including don_redirect meta.

```
DEBUG: Sending cookies to: <GET https://app1.com/pictures/view.php?picid=12>
Cookie: PHPSESSID=4kohgvdbloritctck7ih13pir0
DEBUG: Redirecting (303) to <GET https://app1.com/users/login.php> from <GET https://app1.com/pictures/view.php?picid=12>
```

and I will not get the comment form from view.php.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: We can't access your localhost, so you need to attach a screenshot of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright the login from the scrapy documentation works. It was just a small configuration error with the cookie jars.